# Gridview wordwrap

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

I've tried changing the RowStyle Wrap property and every Wrap property in the grid. How do I stop word wrap in a Gridview no matter what size the Row's Text Length is?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want that column to expand with the length of the text, or do you want the text to just be cut off based on the width of the column?

Comment: Yes, I would like the column to expand. i guess I'm used to writing html in asp classic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not RowStyle. You need to set the wrap setting of the individual Item under the columns.

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField>
        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField>
        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This needs to be done for each individual column. You could set up a method in the code-behind to do it for you though.

Comment: This method worked for me in ASP.NET 4, IE 8. I believe it added a noWrap="noWrap" to the td elements.  noWrap is apparently deprecated however, and adding the following style to td elements would be better:  style="white-space: nowrap".

Comment: @Mike: Sounds about Microsoft's speed. In a more cross-browser compatible method would be to add your style `<ItemStyle CssClass="MyNoWrapStyle" />`.

Answer (score 1):

Jason writes in [this blog post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t121857-gridview-control-limiting-width-and-overflow.html):

I was facing the same problems with the Gridview when loading long text from the database. I tried the DIV method to get with CSS styling to stop the table from expanding all the way to the right. I got it to work now with elipsis showing if the text is too long. However, this means that I can't display the whole text in the gridview which can me misleading to users.

So I added another style called "word-break : break-all" to break the text into chunks that fit properly in the table and got the results I wanted. Below is the parts to my code:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .DisplayDesc { width:500px; word-break: break-all; }
    .DisplayDiv  { width:500px; OVERFLOW:hidden; TEXT-OVERFLOW:ellipsis;}
</style> 

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Log Description">
    <ItemStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="X-Small" 
               HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="True" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="DisplayDiv">
            <asp:Label CssClass="DisplayDesc" ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                       Text='<%# Bind("TransText") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set nowrap in a css class, and apply that class to span tag, and put your lable inside that span tag,

span class="yourclassname" your asp lable tag /span

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me

```
<asp:GridView ID="SomeGridView"  CssClass="gridtext" > 

.gridtext  
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.gridtext table
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.gridtext tr
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.gridtext td
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.gridtext th
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mine is simpler

```
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" AlternatingRowStyle-Wrap="false" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```